# sending error message to console

Tags: c++, console

At run-time, How we can send a error message to console ?

Ex; like assert's job ;

```
assert ( expression ) ;// when it evaluates to false, it send a error message
```

I want to write a code, in more complex ;

```
ASSERT ( expression , error message ) ;
```

How can I do ? ( of course without using cout )

Comment: std::cout shouldn't ever be used for error messages. There is std::cerr for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a technique I have often seen:

```
assert ( <expression> && "Put your message here") ;
```

If expression fails then the assert still fails.
Also assert will put the whole expression into the error (including the message).

Answer (score 1):

[stderr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stderr/) and its [usage](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/10096/)